# Combinatorics card counting question.

Tags: combinatorics

A standard​ 52-card deck of cards is shuffled and then a hand of 10 cards is dealt from the deck.

> How many different outcomes are possible that have exactly $2$ ​pairs,
>   and all other cards of different​ ranks?

Note that a pair consists of two cards of the same​ rank, and each pair must be of a different rank.  An example of a​ 5-card hand with 2 pairs​ is: 7 of​ hearts, 7 of​ clubs, 9 of​ diamonds, 9 of​ clubs, and Queen of spades.

It seems we cannot choose two of the same pair first i start by choosing the two numbers that i will hold pairs of then discount the 8 cards from selection. Then i have 44 left 40 etc. i think i need to multiply by one over 6! to account for the ordering of the numbers i have i selected ?

$${{13}\choose {2}}\cdot44\cdot 40\cdot 36\cdot 32\cdot 28\cdot 24 \cdot \frac{1}{6!} = 147603456$$

I guess my confusion is i could draw the same 10 card hand say say i draw 5 6 7 8 9 3 if i drew 3 5 6 7 8 9 its the same 10 card hand in the end how do i fix that?

Comment: It may often help to first *write out* what you are looking to count. $~$ We favor a selection of two distinct pairs and six distinct singletons. $~$ That is: *2 from 4 suits for each of* 2 from 13 kinds, and 1 from 4 suits for each of 6 from the 11 other kinds.$$\binom 42^2\binom {13}2\binom 41^6 \binom{11}6$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to choose which pairs of cards exactly you take from the two ranks first selected: factor ${4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}$.

Otherwise it is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

One correct approach is as follows.  We can uniquely construct any hand which satisfies the criteria by following the steps below in sequence:

- Select 2 ranks, one for each pair; $\binom {13}2$ possibilities
- Select suits for each pair; $\binom 42$ possibilities for each pair
- Select ranks for the singleton cards; $\binom{11}{6}$ possibilities
- Select suits for each lone card; $4$ possibilities for each card.

With that in mind, the [total number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=C(13,2)*C(4,2)%5E2*C(11,6)*4%5E6) of such hands will be
$$
\binom {13}2 \cdot \binom 42^2 \cdot \binom {11}6 \cdot 4^6 = 5\,313\,724\,416
$$

Comment: Shouldn't that be $4^6$ ? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: And $\binom{11}{6}$

Comment: Good catch; just fixed it

Comment: This works, but the OP's method is more efficient imho. (+1 though)

Comment: NVM i just cant use a calculator thanks all.

Comment: ... where $\binom{11}{6} 4^6 = 44 \cdot 40 \cdot 36 \cdot 32 \cdot 28 \cdot 24 / 6!$ from the OP, which is also correctly figured by just finding the number of possible cards for each of the last 6.  So just the $\binom{4}{2}^2$ was missing.